# How to reach a value in LocalEnvironment Tree in ESQL :: IBM Message Broker

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I'm trying to set `WrittenDestination.Name` to `OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.zipFileName` .
But when I try to run and track the message, value of `zipFileName` is `null`.

Here is my ESQL code.

```
CREATE COMPUTE MODULE TFM_ERecruit_compare
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment = InputLocalEnvironment;
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.zipFileName = InputLocalEnvironment.WrittenDestination.Name;
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.entryFileName = 'test.xml';
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.srcPath = InputLocalEnvironment.WrittenDestination.Directory;
        SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Variables.logger_name = InputLocalEnvironment.Variables.logger_name;
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;
END MODULE;
```

I'm sure that `OutputLocalEnvironment.WrittenDestination.Name` is not null because I have traced already.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I missing `File` in `InputLocalEnvironment.WrittenDestination.Name` expression. It should be  `InputLocalEnvironment.WrittenDestination.File.Name`.